# Flare and Flutter with different devices (screens)

Tags: flutter, flare

i am doing my first steps with flare and flutter and right now its really nice to be able to put animations into flutter without coding them by hand. But i dont understand how to make the flare thingy responsive (how to support different screen sizes).

This is part of a splash screen:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(250, 224, 61, 1.0),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
              child: FlareActor(
                "assets/flare/splash.flr",
                callback: (nameOfAnimation) =>
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/login"),
                fit: BoxFit.none,
                animation: "splash",
              )),
        ));
  }
```

This works well on my iPhone X because the animation is designed for that size. Is there any way how a smaller device can be able to use this same flare animation? Testing this with iPhone SE resulted in a clipped animation.

I hope there is another way than creating several animations for several screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your animation as a child of a `SizedBox` and give it a width/height and you’ll be fine.

You can also use the `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` or `height` to get the viewport dimensions and set your `SizedBox` to use a % of the screen accordingly, if you want to.

Comment: doesnt work. It seems Flare cant rescale its animation no matte what kind of parent container i use.

Comment: You can try to also wrap it in an `OverflowBox` and set the max height and width to your `SizedBox` * 1.10. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use MediaQuery with the current context of your widget and get `width` or `height` in your container or sizedbox like this

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65
```

else If you have a single widget you can use a `FractionallySizedBox` widget to specify a percentage of the available space to fill

```
FractionallySizedBox(
    widthFactor: 0.7,
    heightFactor: 0.3,
    child:FlareActor(
                "assets/flare/splash.flr",
                callback: (nameOfAnimation) =>
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/login"),
                fit: BoxFit.none,
                animation: "splash",
              )),
  );
```

Comment: doesnt work. It seems Flare cant rescale its animation no matte what kind of parent container i use.